# Xcode error when running on device: "Could not allocate a resource"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes

I'm getting the error "Could not allocate a resource" when I try to run on any of my devices.  I've seen this as a possible fix:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/db/lockdown/
```

I've tried that and restarted my machine a handful of times, but no luck.  I also tried changing USB ports.  I've reinstalled Xcode as well after uninstalling with AppCleaner.

In addition to the error, whenever I connect a device it asks me "Trust This Computer?"

This is occurring on an iPhone 5 and iPhone 6+ with lightning, as well as an iPad 3 with the old style connector.

[Updates]
I've now also reinstalled iTunes to no effect.
Also reset PRAM and SMC.

Comment: May be this link can help to find your solution, http://khellek.blogspot.in/2012/10/itunes-could-not-connect-to-this-iphone.html

Comment: Sadly no.  It looks to be more or less the solution above (sudo...).  I even tried recreating the lockdown folder.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After you delete that folder, you need to recreate again and make proper permissions, because iTunes need rw rights to that folder:

```
   sudo mkdir /var/db/lockdown
   sudo chmod go+w  /var/db/lockdown
```

without having iTunes open. Then everything should be fine.
Also keep in mind the same operation may be required for /private/var/db/lockdown [a mirror]

If you moved and old Mac to a new one, make sure  /var/db/lockdown/SystemConfiguration.plist contains your mac actual UUID . Generally it is not recommended to delete a system folder, anyway, without really knowing what you do. ;) Actually I replicated your problem moving /var/db/lockdown to another location, starting iTunes, getting error. Then recreate etc.

Comment: Two and a half weeks of suffering is over.  Thank you sir!  I had recreated the folder but never considered the permissions.

Comment: OMG yes. This is the answer that everyone with this problem has been looking for.

Comment: Solved a problem I had with El Capitan and iOS 10. Upvote.