# Xcode "Could not allocate a resource” when running on device

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated my iMac 2009 to Yosemite and updated to Xcode 6.4 (I haven't used this computer for ~1 year). Everything seems to work fine when i build to the simulator, but if I plug in my iPhone or iPad and try to build to the device I immediately get an error that says "Xcode encountered an error. Could not allocate a resource."

I tried the suggestions here, and a bunch of variations on it, but nothing fixed it for me: [Xcode error when running on device: "Could not allocate a resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254479/xcode-error-when-running-on-device-could-not-allocate-a-resource)

**Update:**

I'm using an iPhone 5 on iOS 8.4 and iPad Air on 8.3. The alert is a pop-down thing in Xcode. Here's a screenshot.

[image]

I should add that running the same code+same version of Xcode+same devices on my laptop (rMBP 2013) works fine

Comment: What model iDevices are you using, and on what iOS versions? And is the alert an actual alert message or an `NSException`? If it's an exception, can you post code and a crash log?

Comment: @DDPWNAGE see update

Comment: Fix the 29 warnings?

Comment: @DDPWNAGE The warnings aren't the issue (and yes, I need to get around to fixing them...) but as I said, the same code builds to my phone just fine when I run it from my laptop, and on my iMac, even a blank project gets the error.