# Why Xcode 9.2 is not recognising trusted IOS 9.3.5 devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9.3, xcode9.2

I updated to Xcode 9.2 recently, and it is not recognising trusted IOS 9.3.5 device, a really old ipad. Can anyone suggest a workaround?
Thanks in Advance.

Update: Also tried connecting to a 11.2.1 Ipad mini. Its also being shown as untrusted device.

[image]

This happens in xcode(for ipad mini4 - trusted when prompted device)

[image]

This happens in iTunes, where the device is still not being recognized even after trusting the mac.

Comment: Did you tried to open Window/Devices and Simulators ?

Comment: Yes, it says not paired, and is advising me to trust the mac on the device, which i already did. This happens in both new and old device. I was working with the both the device before the xcode 9.2 update.

Comment: I have iPad 2 with iOS 9.3.5 installed and it was recognised by Xcode 9.2. What iPad do you have?

Comment: ipad2 and ipad mini4.

Comment: Did you tried to connect your devices to another Mac with Xcode 9.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254479/xcode-error-when-running-on-device-could-not-allocate-a-resource)

Answer worked for me.

After you delete that folder, you need to recreate again and make proper permissions, because iTunes need rw rights to that folder:

```
 sudo mkdir /var/db/lockdown
 sudo chmod go+w  /var/db/lockdown
```

without having iTunes open. Then everything should be fine. Also keep in mind the same operation may be required for /private/var/db/lockdown [a mirror]

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with provisioning profile/developer certificates:

Are the devices included as part of the provisioning profile? And, is the provisioning profile still active? If so, it could also be that you need to go to General -> Profiles and Device Management to trust the developer certificates.